# Linear independence, linear analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Is the following set of vectors from P^3 linearly independent? Give reasons.

[1], [1+2x+3x^2], [1+3x^2]

Comment: Care to show us what you have tried?

Comment: α1[1] + α2[1+2x+3x^2] + α3[1+3x^2] and see if it equals zero is what we learned at school but that doesn't work for this question :/ If it does equal zero when at least one α doesn't equal zero it is linear dependent

Comment: What you learned at school works perfectly well. if you keep in mind that "equals zero" means "equals zero *identically*", that is, for all values of $x$; that is, is the zero polynomial; that is, has all coefficients zero.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, just to clarify, I let α1[1] = 0,  α2[1+2x+3x^2] = 0 and α3[1+3x^2] = 0? @GerryMyerson

Comment: No, you do what you wrote: "α1[1] + α2[1+2x+3x^2] + α3[1+3x^2] and see if it equals zero". I was just telling you what "it equals zero" means. It means that when you multiply all that out and combine like terms you get the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever linear combination of the three polynomials you form, the $x$ term cannot be cancelled out unless the coefficient of the second polynomial is zero. Then whatever linear combination of the remaining two polynomials you form, the $x^2$ cannot be cancelled out unless the coefficient of the last polynomial is zero.